# Trying to sort an ArrayList of value

Tags: ajax

I am attempting to sort an ArrayList in my program which has the functionality of storing different rugby teams and there results in an ArrayList and printing them in the form of a table. I have managed to do everything but the sorting. This is my code so far.

```
package javaCode.RugbyCompetitionTable;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Team{
    private String teamName;
    private int won;
    private int drew;
    private int lost;
    private int scored;
    private int conceded;
    private int scoreDifference;
    private int triesScored;
    private int triesAgainst;

    public Team(String teamName) {
        this.teamName = teamName;
    }

    public String getTeamName() {
        return teamName;
    }

    public int getWon() {
        return won;
    }

    public int getDrew() {
        return drew;
    }

    public int getLost() {
        return lost;
    }

    public int getScored() {
        return scored;
    }

    public int getConceded() {
        return conceded;
    }

    public void setTeamName(String teamName) {
        this.teamName = teamName;
    }

    public int getScoreDifference() {
        return scoreDifference;
    }
```

Comment: You are sorting the teams after printing them.

Comment: ive changed this and it still is producing the same result

Comment: ive just updated the question, thanks.

Comment: i am getting no errors in my code, its just not working.

Comment: The list looks sorted according to your compareTo implementation in Team. It just happens to also correspond to your insert (addTeam()) order. What happens if you move `currentTeams.addTeam(leeds);` to be the last addTeam statement?

Comment: "its just not working" is not a helpful description. Use the form "when I _____, I get _____, when I am expecting _______"

Comment: They are sorted. Why do you think they aren't?

Comment: Is there any way i can compare two values in the ArrayList? Lets say they are ordered in a way where the highest number of points goes first and the lowest at the bottom, which is what i have now been able to accomplish. If the points are the same, I am wanting them to be ordered by points difference. How would i accomplish this? Thanks, Jake. @Michael

Comment: @JakeMellor Yep. Just replace your `return 0` with a second if-statement that compares the points difference.

Comment: By the way, I noticed a bug when looking at this the second time. If a team plays two games, only the tries etc from their latest game are recorded. Leeds should have 22 for, you can see they only have 12. Your `playMatch` method is wrong, but I'll leave it up to you to figure out how to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're sorting based upon which teams beat one another. You presumably want to sort based on the number of points:

```
@Override
public int compareTo (Team team) {
    if (team.getScoreDifference() > this.getScoreDifference()) {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (team.getScoreDifference() < this.getScoreDifference()) {
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
Leeds Rhinos  2  0  0  12   5   7
Sheffield     1  0  0  15  13   2
London        0  1  0  13  13   0
Burnley       0  1  0  10  10   0
Doncaster     0  0  1  12  20  -8
Southampton   0  0  1  10  20 -10
```

You can actually rewrite the `compareTo` much more simply:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Team team) {
    return Integer.compare(team.getScoreDifference(), this.getScoreDifference());
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!!! your answer made me realize what i was doing wrong, much appreciated!

Comment: @JakeMellor Sure, no problem